# get set accessors from static Main() - and best practice for boolean store

Tags: c#

I can't adequately explain why
    Console.WriteLine(val.getSetNum) 
from  static void Main(string[] args) returns 0.

I would have thought that after calc()had been called,    int num    would have been set? I know I can make calc() return the value of needed, but really, I just want to satisfactorily explain to myself the other. Intuitively it doesn't look quite right because it creates a different class instance...

The wider issue, is understanding the best way to store boolean control variables accessed by various classes... instead of making them all static.
Any help appreciated.

```
public class Program
{
    private class Values
    {
        private int num;
        public int getSetNum  {get; set;}
    }

   public int calc()
    {
      Values vals = new Values();
      vals.getSetNum = 6;
      Console.WriteLine(vals.getSetNum);
      return vals.getSetNum;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program prog = new Program();
        Values val = new Values();
        prog.calc();                     //Outputs 6 
        Console.WriteLine(val.getSetNum);//Outputs 0 - why?
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because calc() and your Main() method are both constructing and accessing entirely separate Values() objects. Given that Values is a non-static class, there is no relationship whatsoever between any given instance of Values() and any other, and the same goes for any of the properties therein.

If you were to keep a private Values field in Program, like so:

```
private Values yourValues = new Values();
private class Values
{
...
```

You could access and alter this Values instance in all your methods, and the changes made to yourValues' getSetSum would be reflected each time you access it anywhere in your class.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for! and certainly works across different functions (sorry methods!) within the same class. Still don't understand why static void Main(string[] args) doesn't pick up Values in that way though, still within same superset as it were...

Comment: Cool, if this was helpful to you, click the check mark to select the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating two different instances of `Values` - one inside `Main`, which keeps its value of 0 for `getSetNum`, and one inside `Calc`, which is given a value of 6 for `getSetNum`. They're entirely separate instances.

You could fix this by returning the `Values` reference from `calc` instead. For example:

```
// TODO: Change *all* the names to be meaningful and comply with conventions
public int calc()
{
    Values vals = new Values();
    vals.getSetNum = 6;
    Console.WriteLine(vals.getSetNum);
    return vals;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program prog = new Program();
    Values val = prog.calc();
    Console.WriteLine(val.getSetNum);
}
```

Next:

> The wider issue, is understanding the best way to store boolean control variables accessed by various classes

Well you'd need instances which are referenced by all of those classes. Without more information, it's hard to recommend any particular course of action - but *often* this sort of thing is best handled with dependency injection. But don't think you need to put all of this shared information in a single class - you should keep it partitioned logically. (Again, it's hard to be more specific without a concrete example of what you're trying to do.)

Comment: Specifically, I have a Windows Form with various checkboxes, and these options (as boolean true), need to be placed somewhere that classes within the same namespace can access. As a general principle, I got this to work as a class full of static booleans, but think this is ugly really (?). Your help is appreciated.

Comment: @Chaz: Yes, that's very ugly. You almost certainly shouldn't be trying to share the *form* anyway, but an underlying model. But this is too broad a question to answer easily, I'm afraid... you might want to ask a new question with more specific. (What are the other classes? What creates instances of them? Are they created on application start-up?)

Comment: My prog works as follows - user clicks Start from Windows Form, small bit of code calls a method in a different class which starts a Thread called Main() in yet another class. A loop checks when required the boolean conditions to see if anything else needs to be done (which can be set at any time by the Form controls). I'm not sharing the Form, just sharing this class of booleans to the Form and to any other class... As a beginner I'm pleased this works, but really need to improve this!! - and especially need to find the right resources to read.

Comment: @Chaz: As I said before, you should ask a *new* question with more information.

Comment: thanks, going to do some more thinking over all the issues...:-)

Answer (score 0):

`val` is never set to a value and thus still have its default value of `0` in your Main function.
You need to assign to it a value as in calc.

```
val.getSetNum = 6;
```

if you want calc to assign a value you may pass the value to it

```
public int calc(Values vals)
{
  vals.getSetNum = 6;
  Console.WriteLine(vals.getSetNum);
  return vals.getSetNum;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program prog = new Program();
    Values val = new Values();
    prog.calc(val);                     //Outputs 6 
    Console.WriteLine(val.getSetNum); //Outputs 6 
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```